# Spark: Run through List Asyncronously and perform SparkContext Actions

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

In my application I am running through a list synchronously in order to process all hostnames in a list.

While the application works, the problem is I want to now be able to run through that list asynchronously, however I am not entirely sure how to do this with spark since the SparkContext object is not serializable, meaning you can only have a single SparkContext object running at any given time, preventing you from doing multiple spark actions simultaneously.

So my question is, how do other people approach this problem?  Maybe I am not thinking about it in the right way.

**Possible Solution:** Map List(modelFilteredTopology) to a JavaRDD and then use JavaRDD.foreachAsync(Call MapProcessing with VoidFunction) in order to perform the actions asynchronously.  However I may run into some head scratching issues if I do this.  And I believe I will still be limited by the SparkContext as it wont execute the actions asynchronously anyways.

Sample of my code below:

MainClass.java snippet - Loads some data from a SchemaRDD over to a LIST

```
            List<modelFilteredTopology> filteredList = FILTERED_TOPOLOGY.map(new Function<Row, modelFilteredTopology>() {
            public modelFilteredTopology call(Row row){
                modelFilteredTopology modelF = new modelFilteredTopology();

                modelF.setHOSTNAME(row.getString(0));
                modelF.setMODEL(row.getString(1));
                modelF.setCOMMIT_TS(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

                return modelF;
            }
        }).collect();

        for(modelFilteredTopology f : filteredList) {
            MapProcessing2 map = new MapProcessing2(schemaTopology, sc, sqlContext);
            map.runApp(f.getHOSTNAME(),f.getMODEL(),f.getCOMMIT_TS());
        }
```

MapProcessing2.class - This is a small snippet of the code that performs a TON of JAVARDD transformations, I have to make SparkContext static, otherwise it will obviously through a Serialization not allowed error.

```
public class MapProcessing2 implements Serializable {

private static final Integer HISTORYDATE = 30;
private static JavaSchemaRDD TOPO_EXTRACT;
private static JavaSparkContext SC;
private static JavaSQLContext sqlContext;
private static final String ORACLE_DRIVER = Properties.getString("OracleDB_Driver");
private static final String ORACLE_CONNECTION_URL_PROD = Properties.getString("DB_Connection_PROD");
private static final String ORACLE_USERNAME_PROD = Properties.getString("DB_Username_PROD");
private static final String ORACLE_PASSWORD_PROD = Properties.getString("DB_Password_PROD");

public MapProcessing2(JavaSchemaRDD TOPO_EXTRACT, JavaSparkContext SC, JavaSQLContext sqlContext) {
    this.TOPO_EXTRACT = TOPO_EXTRACT;
    this.SC = SC;
    this.sqlContext = sqlContext;

}
public void runApp(String hostname, String model, String commits) throws Exception{
    if (String.valueOf(hostname).equals("null")) {
        System.out.println("No Value Retrieved");
    } else {
        try {
            //Retrieve Tickets for GWR
            JavaSchemaRDD oltint = getOLTInterfaces(TOPO_EXTRACT, hostname);
            System.out.println("Number of OLT's Found for "+hostname+": " + oltint.collect().size());
            if (oltint.collect().size() < 1) {
                System.out.println("No OLT's found for: " + hostname);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Processing Router: " + hostname + " Model:" + model);

                System.out.println("Processing Tickets for: " + hostname + " " + model);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Processing GWR: " + hostname + " " + model + " Stacktrace Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance what you're doing doesn't make sense.  You clearly expect that `runApp` return some small result set otherwise you  wouldn't collect and check size. Is there any heavy processing involved behind the scenes?

Comment: Nope I dont, the code above is a very small snippet, but at the end of the run execution it doesnt need to return anything to the Mainclass, because the data gets loaded asynchronously to an oracle table once all transformations are complete.  No resultset is returned to the Mainclass once processing is complete, hence the "public void runapp"

Comment: So do you even collect? And what happens there? You really don't want to start Spark job to execute JDBC query and discard the result. This heavy weight and expensive tool.

Comment: Once the transformations are complete and loaded into the final JavaRDD<modelHere>, it executes a JavaRDD.foreachAsync(new OracleLoader())  which implements VoidFunction<modelHere> to run the oracle loader asyncronously.  Therefore the application does not hault when loading the database table with thousands of records.  It simply procceeds to process the next item in the list while the previous JavaRDD's records are being loaded to the oracle table asynchronously.

Comment: It is late but it still doesn't make sense to me why  collect, start job per item and collect inside once again. Not to mention that async action will still block the cluster unless you limit its resources.

Comment: Because the collect is returning different values depending on the hostname from the list.  Its retrieving a list of devices for that hostname.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106520/discussion-between-user2100493-and-zero323).

Comment: You don't really describe what you are doing very well. But is it possible to do it as a `join` instead? As in `join` the list of hostnames to one or many structures, and process the whole resulting product instead of iterating through the hostnames list one at a time. This is easier with DataFrames, BTW, and you already have a SchemaRDD.